# change embeded images to links

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of Excel workbooks each containing many embedded .jpgs.  I'd like to change them to links.  I have done some manually already and found that doing them all manually would be a very arduous task.  Is there a way to do this in VBA? I guess what I would like is some code that would loop through all the images in the workbook and test whether that image is embedded or linked.  If it is already linked, skip to the next image and test again.  If that image is embedded, change it to linked and then process the remaining shapes in the workbook.

Comment: Hi Richard,. Stack overflow works best when you try some code that doesn't work, and post it here, then we can begin to comment

Comment: Therein lies the problem.  I searched the internet and couldn't find any code that does what I want. Excel has a built in feature that allows you to change embedded pictures to links, so I figure that I could use the macro recorder and modify  the code it produces.  So I started the recorder, right-clicked a picture. changed the picture to a link, stopped the recorder and went to examine the code.  Unfortunately, the recorder didn't produce any.

Comment: Hm, I know nothing of the subject matter. Are you able to code a loop that loops through all the images and does something? (prints something). Are you able to code an IF that tests if an image is embedded?

Comment: Yes I can do both a loop and an if test, but do not know what to test.